# Shower Grout Coming Up - How to redo?

Tags: shower, grout

The floor of the shower is a bunch of irregular stones with grout between them. After about 12-16 months in the house the grout started to come up. I suspect that I needed to have reapplied water proofing, and did not. So I went to Lowes and they said
- get unsanded grout
- mix it with water proofing as the liquid

then apply it as regular and it should last forever, i.e. would not need water proofing reapplied. So I scraped out the old grout, mixed per instructions, and applied. This stuff only lasted ~2 months before starting to come up.

What did I do wrong ? My best guess is that I should have used sanded grout instead of unsanded. Any other suggestions?

[image: floor of shower]

Comment: Grout needs some water to hydrate, I do use add mix but not 100%, some waterproofing mixes are only rated for a specific % this may have been the problem.

Comment: Thank you, this is good information because I would have probably made the same mistake again